# Play framework brute-force prevention

Tags: scala, playframework

Is there a solution to timeout login for 15 minutes for a user who entered wrong password more than 5 times?
Maybe play framework could provide some default features? Can't find some relevant information about this one

Comment: @singhakash, how does CSRF relate to entering the wrong password? They're just not connected.

Comment: The correct solution is captcha after x failed retries.